# Why is the Sharepoint Site Owners group missing from Site Permissions?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a dev Sharepoint site with unique permissions (and fake users seen below). In the SharePoint manage access blade, the permissions appear as such:

[image]

However, when I click through to the Advanced Permissions link just below that, the permissions look as such:

[image]

MaksSite Owners is missing in the 2nd listing, though it appears in the first listing. This group appears to be the default Owners group that came with the SharePoint site. It is also missing when queried through the SharePoint REST API (via `/sites/MaksSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MaksSite/path/to/file')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments?$expand=member`). Which listing is right, and if it is the first listing, how do I get it to appear, at least with the API?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Site Owners group is hidden in the list. To make it appear, please take the following steps:

- Click List Settings under Settings.

[image]

- Scroll down to Views, click Detail View.
  [image]
- In Filter section, choose show all items in this view. Then save the view.

[image]

The Site Onwers group will appear in the list:

[image]

You could try to use the below Rest API:

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/michael/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/groups?$expand=users
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This did not work for me (the group is still not showing up for the item in question). I also doubt it would help as a Sharepoint REST API user. The owner group is not showing up there either. Is there, perhaps, an implied rule that the owners group has access to all items, and therefore is omitted?

Comment: Per my test, the Ownwes group would be shown through Rest API, this is the endpoint I use: /_api/Web/SiteGroups/getbyname('michael Owners')/users

Comment: For a file, try to use this: /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/michael/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/groups?$expand=users